# How to make dynamic tree view every node independently

Tags: angular-material, treeview

I met a problem while I implemented a angular application with material tree view.
thie tree view is dyniamic, that means that you can add child node if you click add button.

the HTML code looks like this

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node"
                  [checked]="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)"
                  (change)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNoContent" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput #itemValue placeholder="New item...">
    </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
            <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="locationField" [(ngModel)]="node.field" name="node" [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Field"/>
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let filteredFieldResult of locationFieldResults" [value]="filteredFieldResult">
                {{filteredFieldResult}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button (click)="saveNode(node, itemValue.value)">Save</button>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="descendantsAllSelected(node)"
                  [indeterminate]="descendantsPartiallySelected(node)"
                  (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(node)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

you can see that I have a input field with autocomplet.

and the ts code is as follow:

```
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {FlatTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTreeFlatDataSource, MatTreeFlattener} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
/**
 * Node for to-do item
 */
export class TodoItemNode {
  children: TodoItemNode[];
  item: string;
}

/** Flat to-do item node with expandable and level information */
export class TodoItemFlatNode {
  item: string;
  level: number;
  expandable: boolean;
}

/**
 * The Json object for to-do list data.
 */
const TREE_DATA = {
  Groceries: {
    'Almond Meal flour': null,
    'Organic eggs': null,
    'Protein Powder': null,
    Fruits: {
      Apple: null,
      Berries: ['Blueberry', 'Raspberry'],
      Orange: null
    }
  },
  Reminders: [
    'Cook dinner',
    'Read the Material Design spec',
    'Upgrade Application to Angular'
  ]
};

/**
 * Checklist database, it can build a tree structured Json object.
 * Each node in Json object represents a to-do item or a category.
 * If a node is a category, it has children items and new items can be added under the category.
 */
@Injectable()
export class ChecklistDatabase {
  dataChange = new BehaviorSubject<TodoItemNode[]>([]);

  get data(): TodoItemNode[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

  constructor() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    // Build the tree nodes from Json object. The result is a list of `TodoItemNode` with nested
    //     file node as children.
    const data = this.buildFileTree(TREE_DATA, 0);

    // Notify the change.
    this.dataChange.next(data);
  }

  /**
   * Build the file structure tree. The `value` is the Json object, or a sub-tree of a Json object.
   * The return value is the list of `TodoItemNode`.
   */
  buildFileTree(obj: {[key: string]: any}, level: number): TodoItemNode[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce<TodoItemNode[]>((accumulator, key) => {
      const value = obj[key];
      const node = new TodoItemNode();
      node.item = key;

      if (value != null) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          node.children = this.buildFileTree(value, level + 1);
        } else {
          node.item = value;
        }
      }

      return accumulator.concat(node);
    }, []);
  }

  /** Add an item to to-do list */
  insertItem(parent: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    if (parent.children) {
      parent.children.push({item: name} as TodoItemNode);
      this.dataChange.next(this.data);
    }
  }

  updateItem(node: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    node.item = name;
    this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  }
}

/**
 * @title Tree with checkboxes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tree-checklist-example',
  templateUrl: 'tree-checklist-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tree-checklist-example.css'],
  providers: [ChecklistDatabase]
})
export class TreeChecklistExample {
  /** Map from flat node to nested node. This helps us finding the nested node to be modified */
  flatNodeMap = new Map<TodoItemFlatNode, TodoItemNode>();

  /** Map from nested node to flattened node. This helps us to keep the same object for selection */
  nestedNodeMap = new Map<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>();
  public locationField: FormControl = new FormControl();
  public locationFieldResults = ["abc", "asdfa", "asdfasd"]
  /** A selected parent node to be inserted */
  selectedParent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = null;

  /** The new item's name */
  newItemName = '';

  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>;

  treeFlattener: MatTreeFlattener<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>;

  dataSource: MatTreeFlatDataSource<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>;

  /** The selection for checklist */
  checklistSelection = new SelectionModel<TodoItemFlatNode>(true /* multiple */);

  constructor(private _database: ChecklistDatabase) {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(this.transformer, this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable, this.getChildren);
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

    _database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    });

    this.locationField.valueChanges.subscribe(inputField => {
        this.filterField(inputField);
      }
    );
  }

  getLevel = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.level;

  isExpandable = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.expandable;

  getChildren = (node: TodoItemNode): TodoItemNode[] => node.children;

  hasChild = (_: number, _nodeData: TodoItemFlatNode) => _nodeData.expandable;

  hasNoContent = (_: number, _nodeData: TodoItemFlatNode) => _nodeData.item === '';

  /**
   * Transformer to convert nested node to flat node. Record the nodes in maps for later use.
   */
  transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
    const existingNode = this.nestedNodeMap.get(node);
    const flatNode = existingNode && existingNode.item === node.item
        ? existingNode
        : new TodoItemFlatNode();
    flatNode.item = node.item;
    flatNode.level = level;
    flatNode.expandable = !!node.children;
    this.flatNodeMap.set(flatNode, node);
    this.nestedNodeMap.set(node, flatNode);
    return flatNode;
  }

  /** Whether all the descendants of the node are selected. */
  descendantsAllSelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected = descendants.every(child =>
      this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child)
    );
    return descAllSelected;
  }

  /** Whether part of the descendants are selected */
  descendantsPartiallySelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const result = descendants.some(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    return result && !this.descendantsAllSelected(node);
  }

  /** Toggle the to-do item selection. Select/deselect all the descendants node */
  todoItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node)
      ? this.checklistSelection.select(...descendants)
      : this.checklistSelection.deselect(...descendants);

    // Force update for the parent
    descendants.every(child =>
      this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child)
    );
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /** Toggle a leaf to-do item selection. Check all the parents to see if they changed */
  todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /* Checks all the parents when a leaf node is selected/unselected */
  checkAllParentsSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    let parent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = this.getParentNode(node);
    while (parent) {
      this.checkRootNodeSelection(parent);
      parent = this.getParentNode(parent);
    }
  }

  /** Check root node checked state and change it accordingly */
  checkRootNodeSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    const nodeSelected = this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected = descendants.every(child =>
      this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child)
    );
    if (nodeSelected && !descAllSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.deselect(node);
    } else if (!nodeSelected && descAllSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.select(node);
    }
  }

  /* Get the parent node of a node */
  getParentNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode): TodoItemFlatNode | null {
    const currentLevel = this.getLevel(node);

    if (currentLevel < 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const startIndex = this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node) - 1;

    for (let i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
      const currentNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes[i];

      if (this.getLevel(currentNode) < currentLevel) {
        return currentNode;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  /** Select the category so we can insert the new item. */
  addNewItem(node: TodoItemFlatNode) {
    const parentNode = this.flatNodeMap.get(node);
    this._database.insertItem(parentNode!, '');
    this.treeControl.expand(node);
  }

  /** Save the node to database */
  saveNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode, itemValue: string) {
    const nestedNode = this.flatNodeMap.get(node);
    this._database.updateItem(nestedNode!, itemValue);
  }

  private filterField(value: string): string[] {
    if (value) {
      this.locationFieldResults = this.locationFieldResults.filter((searchFieldResult) => {
        return searchFieldResult.indexOf(value) !== -1;
      });

    } else {
      this.locationFieldResults = this.locationFieldResults;
    }
    return this.locationFieldResults;
  }
}
```

the problem is: If I tipped some content in input field, by adding new child node, the tipped content in old input field disappeared.

any solutions are expected.

this is example from angular material, you can copy the html and ts file into it,

https://stackblitz.com/angular/nnxeaxmrdob?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

Comment: Check some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991164/angular-material-tree-different-parent-child-types